# How to correct my code for solving the Josephus problem?

Tags: programming, combinatorics

#### Problem Description

Recently, I have been reading the book *Schaum's Outline of Mathematica (2nd Edition)*, where I encountered the problem:

> Flavius Josephus was a Jewish historian of the first century. He wrote about a group of ten Jews in a cave who, rather than surrender to the Romans, chose to commit suicide, one by one. They formed a circle and every other one was killed. Who was the lone survivor?

**The author's solution:**

```
list = Range[10];
While[Length[list] > 1, list = Rest[RotateLeft[list]]];
list
```

> {5}

However, I know it is not efficient to use the procedural methods such as `Do`, `While`, etc. Rather, I want to use a functional method like `NestWhile`, `Nest`, or `FixedPoint` to solve the problem.

**My solutions:**

Method 1:

```
list = Range @ 10; 
NestList[Rest @ RotateLeft[#] &, list, 9]
```

> ```
>  {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, 
>   {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1}, 
>   {5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 3}, 
>   {7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 3, 5}, 
>   {9, 10, 1, 3, 5, 7}, 
>   {1, 3, 5, 7, 9}, 
>   {5, 7, 9, 1}, 
>   {9, 1, 5}, 
>   {5, 9},
>   {5}}
> ```

Furthermore, this method has the flaw that I must give the number of iterations. In fact, sometimes that is unknown.

Method 2:

```
list = Range @10;
FixedPoint[If[Length@# != 1 &, Rest @ RotateLeft[#] &], list]
```

Unfortunately, method 2 doesn't work.

Method 3:

```
 list = Range @ 10;
 NestWhileList[Rest @ RotateLeft[#] &, list, Length@list != 1]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}
> ```

So my question is: what is a good way to do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
NestWhile[Rest @ RotateLeft @ # &, Range @ 10, Length @ # > 1 &]
```

> {5}

```
FixedPoint[If[Length @ # > 1, Rest @ RotateLeft[#], #] &, Range @ 10]
```

**Edit**

Historical note: As far as I can remember, Josephus roulette (a plain treason to his companions) consisted of killing every *third* person.

```
FixedPoint[If[Length@# != 1, Rest@RotateLeft[#, 2], #] &, Range@10]
```

> {4}

Note: The direction *is* important. `RotateRight[]` will select another victim.

Comment: Dear belisarius,thanks for your help sincerely.Since I am a chinese student,it is the first time for me to know  this hostorical story.

Comment: @mathematica Josephus was a traitor to his own people. He wrote pamphlets that now (2K years after the fact) can be considered "history", but at that time it was plain propaganda.

Comment: @mathematica BTW your question is nicely formulated, with a clear problem statement and showing your efforts to solve the problem. Keep posting like that!

Answer (score 17):

Here's my solution using pattern-matching:

```
Range[10] //. {x_, y_, z___} :> {z, x}
```

> {5}

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Nest` and define a function so you don't have to know the number of iterations:

```
josephus[n_] := Nest[Rest@RotateLeft[#] &, Range@n, n - 1]
```

So

```
josephus[10]
```

> {5}

```
josephus[200]
```

> {145}

Answer (score 6):

A way without using any of `Nest`, `NestWhile` and `FixedPoint`.

```
josephus[x_ /; Length[x] > 1] := josephus[Rest[RotateLeft[x]]]
josephus[x_] := First@x

josephus[10]
```

> 5

```
josephus[200]
```

> 145

Comment: This didn't work for me until I added a function that turned the x integer into a Range ie, josephus[x_Integer] := josephus[Range[x]]

Answer (score 4):

The following solution, which gives the number of the survivor when every $q$-th person in a group of $n$ persons is killed, is adapted from *[Concrete Mathematics](http://books.google.com/books?id=pntQAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA81)*:

```
josephus[n_Integer?Positive, q_Integer?Positive] /; q <= n := 
         q n - NestWhile[Ceiling[q #/(q - 1)] &, 1, # <= n (q - 1) &, 1] + 1
```

Test:

```
josephus[10, 2] (* OP's case *)
   5

josephus[41, 3] (* Josephus's original problem *)
   31
```

---

For the case $q=2$, [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JosephusProblem.html) gives a nice closed form:

```
With[{n = 10}, 2 n - 2^IntegerLength[n, 2] + 1]
   5
```

Comment: J.M. Thanks for your solution. I used the *Mathematica* about three years ago, then I known this professional site inadvertently.

Answer (score 3):

For this particular scenario (every second person), the last person is the single cyclic shift to the left of the binary representation of the starting number:

```
j[u_] := FromDigits[RotateLeft[First @ RealDigits[u, 2]], 2]
```