# Pare down list recursively

Tags: list-manipulation, recursion

What is the best way to pare down a list whereby the $n$th number is removed from the list recursively? This

```
a = Range[15]; nu = 6;
b = DeleteCases[  Table[If[Mod[a[[n]], nu] == 0, 0, a[[n]]], {n, 1, Length@a}], 0]
c = Join[Take[b, -Mod[Length@a, nu]],   Take[b, Length@b - Mod[Length@a, nu]]]
d = DeleteCases[  Table[If[Mod[n, nu] == 0, 0, c[[n]]], {n, 1, Length@c}], 0]
e = Join[Take[d, -Mod[Length@b, nu]],   Take[d, Length@d - Mod[Length@b, nu]]]
f = DeleteCases[  Table[If[Mod[n, nu] == 0, 0, e[[n]]], {n, 1, Length@e}], 0]
g = Join[Take[f, -Mod[Length@c, nu]],   Take[f, Length@f - Mod[Length@c, nu]]]
h = DeleteCases[  Table[If[Mod[n, nu] == 0, 0, g[[n]]], {n, 1, Length@g}], 0]
i = Join[Take[h, -Mod[Length@d, nu]],   Take[h, Length@h - Mod[Length@d, nu]]]
j = DeleteCases[  Table[If[Mod[n, nu] == 0, 0, i[[n]]], {n, 1, Length@i}], 0]
k = Join[Take[j, -Mod[Length@e, nu]],   Take[j, Length@j - Mod[Length@e, nu]]]
l = DeleteCases[  Table[If[Mod[n, nu] == 0, 0, k[[n]]], {n, 1, Length@k}], 0]
m = Join[Take[l, -Mod[Length@f, nu]],   Take[l, Length@l - Mod[Length@f, nu]]]
n = DeleteCases[  Table[If[Mod[n, nu] == 0, 0, m[[n]]], {n, 1, Length@m}], 0]
o = Join[Take[n, -Mod[Length@g, nu]],   Take[n, Length@n - Mod[Length@g, nu]]]
p = DeleteCases[  Table[If[Mod[n, nu] == 0, 0, o[[n]]], {n, 1, Length@o}], 0]
```

is clearly not good practice, but hopefully it gets across the idea. I tried using `Nest` without success - not sure what is best way to attack it.

Comment: I have trouble follow the logic by which the elements of the list are reordered; would you comment on that?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard it is as though the elements are arranged in a circle and the $6$th element is knocked out on each cycle. The rearranging is just to simulate that they are arranged in a circle and the cycle is continuous till the list is pared down to just $1$ element.

Comment: So it is not strictly necessary for your output so long as the elements that you show remain at each step?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard no, not at all - just didn't know how to do it concisely!

Comment: Okay, I *think* I understand and I am trying to think of a clean way to write that.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard great, thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's find out if I understand the problem and if this works:

```
fn[nu_][{o_, a_}] := {# - 1, Delete[a, #]} & @ Mod[nu + o, Length@a, 1]

NestList[fn[6], {0, Range@15}, 14][[All, 2]] // Column
```

> ```
> {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15}
> {1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15}
> {1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,13,14,15}
> {1,2,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,13,14,15}
> {1,2,4,5,7,8,9,11,13,14,15}
> {1,4,5,7,8,9,11,13,14,15}
> {1,4,5,7,8,9,13,14,15}
> {1,4,7,8,9,13,14,15}
> {1,4,7,8,9,13,14}
> {1,4,7,8,9,14}
> {1,4,7,8,14}
> {1,4,7,8}
> {1,7,8}
> {7,8}
> {7}
> ```

Comment: AH! That's it - brilliant! :)

Comment: @martin Please check the output carefully; I am not certain of my logic regarding `Mod`.

Comment: yes, just checked - looks good to me - `NestList` - that was it!

Comment: @martin Okay, I'll try to simplify this a bit.

Comment: It looks great as it is to me - presentation is really clear

Comment: @martin Alright, I'll leave it be.  I'm glad I could help! :-)

Comment: Great - thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 3):

```
g[list_, incr_] := Module[{i = 1},
               NestWhileList[ Delete[#, i = Mod[i+incr-1, Length@#, 1]] &, list, Length@# > 1 &]]

g[Range@15, 6] // Column

(*{
 {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
 {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
 {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15},
 {1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15},
 {1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14, 15},
 {1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14, 15},
 {1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 13, 14, 15},
 {1, 4, 7, 8, 9, 13, 14, 15},
 {1, 4, 7, 8, 9, 13, 14},
 {1, 4, 7, 8, 9, 14},
 {1, 4, 7, 8, 14},
 {1, 4, 7, 8},
 {1, 7, 8},
 {7, 8}
 {7}
}*)
```

Comment: another great approach - hank you fro your help here! :)

Answer (score 3):

```
josephus[nu_, list_] :=
 NestList[Rest@RotateLeft[#, nu - 1] &, list, Length[list] - 1]

josephus[6, Range[15]]
(*
{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
 {7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
 {13, 14, 15, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11},
 {4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 1, 2},
 {11, 13, 14, 15, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9},
 {4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14, 15, 1},
 {13, 14, 15, 1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9},
 {7, 8, 9, 13, 14, 15, 1, 4},
 {1, 4, 7, 8, 9, 13, 14},
 {14, 1, 4, 7, 8, 9},
 {14, 1, 4, 7, 8},
 {1, 4, 7, 8},
 {7, 8, 1},
 {7, 8},
 {7}}
*)
```

Well it gets the right set but in the wrong order :( -- which can be put right :) like this:

```
RotateRight[#, First[Ordering[#, -1]]] & /@ josephus[6, Range[15]]
(* output that matches (at least) two other answers *)
```

Still, I liked the basic idea of [`josephus`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem), that of spinning the circle around to the executioner, instead of figuring out how far he has to go around to kill the next element.  No need to `Mod` anything.  If you imagine the circle on a spring as it is rotated left, then what the fix does is let the spring unwind.

Comment: this is an interesting approach - It never ceases to amaze me the ingenuity of ansers on this site! :)

Comment: @martin Also http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33595/193

Comment: @belisarius thanks - will check that one out too :)