# Josephus problem

Tags: functions

See [the Josephus Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem). My code takes in two numbers; one is the number of participants, and the other is supposed to be the number of players skipped between executions.

```
josephus[m_Integer, n_Integer] :=
 If[m == 1,
  m,
  Mod[josephus[m - 1, n] + n - 1, m] + 1]
```

The problem is that this code actually takes in the number of participants, and the other number `n` is actually killing the $n^{th}$ player. I don't want that; I want to *skip* $n$ players. (I.e., I want to kill every $(n+1)^{th}$ player.)

Why is it that replacing `n` in my code with `n+1` does not correct the problem? It gives me totally different values. Since my code works fine if we are killing every $n^{th}$ player, shouldn't I just simply change `n` to `n+1` and the code then kills every $(n+1)^{th}$ player?

**Just so it helps, `josephus[40,6]` should return `24`. `josephus[40,5]` should return `28`.** Note that currently, `josephus[40,7]` returns `24` and `josephus[40,6]` returns `28`, which makes sense. The only difference is that, currently, we kill every $n^{th}$ player. I want to kill every $(n+1)^{th}$ player. Why is it that changing `n` to `n+1` doesn't work?

**Edit**: the output represents the player that survives the game.

Comment: Related: [33595](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33595), [64262](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64262)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-liner

```
josephus[howmany_Integer?Positive, which_Integer?Positive] := 
 Nest[Rest[RotateLeft[#, which]] &, Range[howmany], howmany - 1]
```

By the way the explicit formula for the problem is given in Knuth [book](http://www.matematica.net/portal/e-books/Graham%20-%20Knuth%20-%20Patashnik%20-%20%20Concrete%20Mathematics.pdf)
.

Comment: Your solution is equivalent to the one used in method 1 in [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33595/193) which was already linked in the comment done by @MichaelE2 under the question

Comment: Yes indeed, the problem is too simple :). This is obvious implementation of the section 1.3, where it is considered much more deeply.

Comment: Your solution works well, but keep in mind that I was asking why I can't replace `n` with `n+1` in my existing code.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you didn't make a mistake? Perhaps you didn't replace both instances of `n` with `n+1`?

```
josephus1[m_Integer, n_Integer] := 
 If[m == 1, m, Mod[josephus[m - 1, n + 1] + n, m] + 1]
```

`josephus1[40, 6]` returns `24` and `josephus1[40, 5]` returns `28`.

Comment: You replaced `n` with `n+1`, but you also defined a new function `josephus1` that calls the original `josephus`. It works but I still don't see why it works this way.

Comment: I see what you're saying; I ended up doing `josephus1[m_Integer, n_Integer] := josephus[m, n + 1]`, I think this form is clearer about "why" it works. I think the recursion as you tried to define just isn't "invariant" in the way you're expecting it to be. I'm sure there's a more intuitive explanation, but I haven't been able to put a finger on it. I'll try to think more carefully about it a bit later.

Comment: I know what you're saying, and I figured that was the problem, but I'm trying to pinpoint the problem in the recursion.