# Why does this memoized function cause the kernel to quit?

Tags: warning-messages, recursion, kernel, linux, memoization

The following memoized recursive function causes the kernel to beep and quit.

```
$RecursionLimit = 30000
S[k_, i_ /; i < 1] := 0
S[k_ /; k <= 0, i_] := Boole[k == 0]
S[k_, i_] := S[k, i] = Mod[S[k, i - 1] + Prime[i] S[k - Prime[i], i], 10^9]
S[50000, PrimePi[50000]]
```

I looked at memory usage with htop and it doesn't seem like my computer has run out of memory. For reference I am running Mathematica 12.0 (Student Edition) on Ubuntu 18.04.3 with 16 GB RAM.

Update: I tried updating to Mathematica 12.1 on Ubuntu but got the same error.

It works for Mathematica 12.1 on my Windows computer, but not for larger values of `k` (the whole point of memoization). I have edited the above code's last line for easier testing. The original call that failed on linux was `S[Fibonacci[5],5000]`.

I suspect the kernel is running out of memory like described in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/203584/44212).

Comment: This does not help much, but I cannot reproduce that behavior with version 12.0 on macos 10.15.3.

Comment: Works fine on my version 12.1 on macOS 10.14.6.

Comment: Works fine for me 12.1 / Win 10

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Can you try again with the increased value of k?

Comment: I can reproduce this bug with versions 12.1, 12.0 and 11.0 on Fedora 30. My machine has 32 GiB of RAM and the amount of free memory doesn't decrease significantly while running this code. Since Windows and macOS do not seem to be affected, I would suspect that this one is Linux specific.
@qwk Can you report this behavior to WRI?

Comment: Anytime you are dramatically increasing recursion limit, you run the risk of stack exhaustion on your particular machine. I'm not sure recursing 30,000 is advisable, I would recommend alternative algorithms perhaps. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)#Stack_space

Comment: @vsht I emailed support and the issue has been forwarded to the developers. So hopefully we see a fix in the next release.

Comment: @user6014 this particular DP problem can be written iteratively such that it only uses a single list of size k_max. The purpose of this code was to test out Mathematica's memoization capabilities. However Mathematica seems to use a lot more memoization space than pypy. According to my rough estimation Mathematica uses 160 bytes to memoize each result, which while not terrible, could be an order of magnitude less memory if stored absolutely as compactly as possible in a 2D array.

Comment: pypy used roughly 40 bytes per memoization which comes down to however pypy implements hash tables (python dicts).

Comment: The issue in this case is not memory consumption. It is stack exhaustion due to deep recursion. Removing the memoization will show the same result.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a duplicate of [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/203429/recursive-solution-to-the-extended-josephus-problem/203584#203584) which, oddly enough, was closed as a duplicate of another post unrelated to the current one (hence the lengthy explanation).